# Package 'ros1_bridge` not found

Tags: ros, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

This is the guide that I followed: https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge/tree/foxy (I am stuck on attempting example 1).

I was successful in building ros1_bridge with colcon (took about 20 mins). I am trying to do the first example. Note that I am bridging neotic (ros1) to foxy (ros2) so I have cloned the ros1_bridge repository from the foxy tree.

In shell A, I sourced ros1 then ran roscore. In shell B, I sourced ros1 then sourced ros2. Then when I try to run:

`ros2 run ros1_bridge dynamic_bridge`

I get the error

`Package 'ros1_bridge' not found.`

Am I missing anything here?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410063/package-%27ros1_bridge%60-not-found/) by [jacobsayono](https://answers.ros.org/users/125644/jacobsayono/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2022-11-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacobsayono](https://answers.ros.org/users/125644/jacobsayono/) on 2022-11-30**:
ros1 and ros2 works perfectly btw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found out after a day of checking around! I'm a beginner and the tutorial doesn't mention it, but ros1_bridge works as a `workspace folder` so you'd have to source that workspace.

In `.bashrc`, I alias 3 things:

`alias noetic='source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash'`

`alias foxy='source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash'`

`alias bridge='source ~/ros1_bridge/install/setup.bash'`

That way, when you want to run `ros1_bridge`, which is a ros2 workspace, you can use 1 terminal for this. Your terminal command lines should be something like:

$ noetic

$ foxy

$ bridge

$ ros2 run ros1_bridge dynamic_bridge

in this order!

I hope this helps new beginners trying to get into ROS2 and ROS1!

---

Originally posted by [jacobsayono](https://answers.ros.org/users/125644/jacobsayono/) with karma: 16 on 2022-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nartmangnourt](https://answers.ros.org/users/143866/nartmangnourt/) on 2023-06-23**:
Hey jacob,

i still get this output in the terminal:
No executable found